# Run fichier.sql in QGIS python console

Tags: qgis

i use QGIS and i want to know how to run a sql code (fichier.sql) in python console in QGIS

I have used this :

```
impost os 
os.system("psql \i C:/fichier.sql -d test2 ")
```

but it doesn't work 
 Any Help !!!

Comment: What is your goal? It's not possible to simply run SQL from the Python console. We need to know what you are trying to achieve to suggest solutions.

Comment: I need to assign my Database with a script python that use the file.sql

Answer (score 1):

If you work in Python, you must use one of the appropriate Python modules like [psycopg2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psycopg2).

If you want to call an external command (psql), see [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python) or [Execute External Programs, the Python Ways](http://www.zhihua-lai.com/acm/execute-external-programs-the-python-ways/):

- os.system("some_command with args") is deprecated (see [Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module¶](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements))
- it is recommended to use now the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

The best example of the use of this module is given by the [sextante](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/sextante/) plugin wich use it to call R, GRASS GIS or SAGA GIS

1. it creates the command in a temporary file (sextante_script.r or grass.script.sh (or .bat))
2. it executes the command with subprocess.Popen:

with R:

```
command = ["R", "CMD","BATCH", "--vanilla", RUtils.getRScriptFilename(), RUtils.getConsoleOutputFilename()]
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
```

with GRASS GIS

```
command = "grass64 " + GrassUtils.grassMapsetFolder() + "/user"
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True).stdout
```